# The complement set of uncountable is countable?

Tags: analysis

I see a sentence from the solution: ut when all
$A_i$ are not countable means at least one say $A_j$
is uncountable. Then $A_j^c$
is
countable.

Is this true? The complement of a uncountable set must be countable?

The question is Papa rudin exercise 1.6.

[image]

Comment: The question is totally out of context. Tell us exactly what you are reading.

Comment: It does say near the top that "$\mathfrak M$ be the collection of all sets $E\subset X$ such that either $E$ or $E^c$ is at most countable..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clearly stated that if $ E \in \mathfrak{M} $ then at least one of $ E $ or $ E^c  $ is countable. Generally this is not  the case.  In $ \mathbb{R} $, if $A = [0,1]$, then both $A$ and its complement are uncountable.